# How do I tweak binning for dc.js and crossfilter? Is that the performance bottleneck?

Tags: d3.js, analytics, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to make a generic cross filter that can take in a csv and build a dashboard. Here are working examples:

- https://ubershmekel.github.io/gfilter/?dl=https://ubershmekel.github.io/csvData/spent.csv
- https://ubershmekel.github.io/gfilter/?dl=https://ubershmekel.github.io/csvData/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv

But for some reason the flight data is slow and unresponsive. Compare these 2 which analyze the same data:

- https://ubershmekel.github.io/gfilter/?dl=https://ubershmekel.github.io/csvData/flights-3m.csv
- https://github.com/square/crossfilter

I think it's because the histogram binning is too detailed but I can't find a good way to tweak that in the api reference. @gordonwoodhull [mentioned](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1044):

> If the binning is wrong you really want to look at the way you've set up crossfilter - dc.js just uses what it is given.

How do I tweak the binning of crossfilter? I've tried messing with the [xUnits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191258/properly-display-bin-width-in-barchart-using-dc-js-and-crossfilter-js), `dimension` and `group` rounding to no avail.

[This is the problem code I suspect is slow/wrong](https://github.com/ubershmekel/gfilter/blob/317a5192909359003fccefddc228efb42c2c3e7a/assets/gfilter.js#L54):

```
    var dim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d[propName]; });

    if (isNumeric(data[0][propName])) {
        var theChart = dc.barChart("#" + chartId);

        var countGroup = dim.group().reduceCount();
        var minMax = d3.extent(data, function (d) { return +d[propName] });
        var min = +minMax[0];
        var max = +minMax[1];
        theChart
            .width(gfilter.width).height(gfilter.height)
            .dimension(dim)
            .group(countGroup)
            .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([min, max]))
            .elasticY(true);
        theChart.yAxis().ticks(2);
```

Comment: Crossfilter is a separate library from dc.js - you want to adjust how you call `ndx.dimension()` and `dim.group()`. Unfortunately [the documentation is rather dense](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference) but you can take some hints from [how they initialize the dimensions and groups for the crossfilter demo](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L231-L240)

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust binning by passing a function that adjusts values to the `group()` method.  For example, this group would create integer bins:

```
var countGroup = dim.group(function (v) { return Math.floor(v); });
```

And this one would create bins of 20 units a piece:

```
var countGroup = dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / 20) * 20 });
```

Factoring out a variable for bin size:

```
var bin = 20;  // or any integer
var countGroup = dim.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / bin) * bin });
```

If you use binning, you'll also likely want your bars to be of a width matching your bin size. To do so, add a call to `xUnits()` on your bar chart.  `xUnits()` sets the number of points on the axis:

```
.xUnits(function(start, end, xDomain) { return (end - start) / bin; })
```

See the documentation for [crossfilter dimension group()](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_group), [dc.js xUnits()](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#coordinategridmixinxunits--function--coordinategridmixin)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the results at:

https://ubershmekel.github.io/gfilter/?dl=testData/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv

This worked for me. I had to avoid 3 pitfalls: the `group()` function needed to round to the bar locations, `xUnits` needed the amount of bars, and making the `domain` (x axis) show the max value.

```
var numericValue = function (d) {
    if (d[propName] === "")
        return NaN;
    else
        return +d[propName];
};
var dimNumeric = ndx.dimension(numericValue);
var minMax = d3.extent(data, numericValue);
var min = minMax[0];
var max = minMax[1];
var barChart = dc.barChart("#" + chartId);
// avoid very thin lines and a barcode-like histogram
var barCount = 30;
var span = max - min;
lastBarSize = span / barCount;
var roundToHistogramBar = function (d) {
    if (isNaN(d) || d === "")
        d = NaN;
    if (d == max)
        // This fix avoids the max value always being in its own bin (max).
        // I should figure out how to make the grouping equation better and avoid this hack. 
        d = max - lastBarSize;
    var res = min + span * Math.floor(barCount * (d - min) / span) / barCount;
    return res;
};
var countGroup = dimNumeric.group(roundToHistogramBar);
barChart.xUnits(function () { return barCount; });
barChart
    .width(gfilter.width).height(gfilter.height)
    .dimension(dimNumeric)
    .group(countGroup)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([min - lastBarSize, max + lastBarSize]).rangeRound([0, 500]))
    .elasticY(true);
barChart.yAxis().ticks(2);
```