# How to keep the size of the bar constant on my bar chart

Tags: dc.js

Using dc.js, I want to keep the size of the bar constant on my bar chart.

The number of bars may vary from 1 to 10. Currently when there is only one bar it occupies the complete chart space.

I tried limiting the bar width by adding

```
MAX_BAR_WIDTH = 250;
```

but now the ticks and bar position do not match.

Comment: Please share working fiddle? May be this link will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191258/properly-display-bin-width-in-barchart-using-dc-js-and-crossfilter-js

Answer (score 0):

Automatic calculation of the domain is a feature which can be turned off. The bar width will be calculated based on the domain and the number of bars which can be shown in that domain.

You should probably set the x domain manually and turn off "elastic":

```
var minX, maxX; // calculate these however you want
chart
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([minX, maxX])
    .elasticX(false)
```

Documentation:

- [`coordinateGridMixin.x`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html#x__anchor)
- [`coordinateGridMixin.elasticX`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html#elasticX__anchor)